# What property must a RNG have to be used in Monte Carlo simulations?

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, random-generation, probabilistic-programming

For example, every [cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator (CSPRNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) is required to satisfy the next-bit test and withstand "state compromise extensions". This makes me wonder what properties must a RNG have to be used in a Monte Carlo simulation.

It appears that most people just use `runif` or `sample.int` in R, but are they really good enough? Please note that I expect the answer to be language-agnostic, as I might switch to C, Clojure or even SQL at some time.

I find this question interesting because such a RNG must be random enough to produce quality result, and at the same time not as CPU-expensive as CSPRNGs due to performance concerns.

Comment: In addition to Xi'an's observations, you might have a glance at section 4.2 of [this paper](https://www.informs-sim.org/wsc07papers/007.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Similar questions [have been asked](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/227061/7224) on [X validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/350964/7224). Assuming they pass [statistical tests of randomness](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/testu01.pdf), a main issue with RNGs in Monte Carlo simulation is their use in [parallel computation](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/23547/18407), where [special libraries](https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/tag/prng/) must be used to prevent correlations between the threads. There are aso a few studies in the literature about the impact of dependencies in the RNGs, as in [Murray and Elliott (2012)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.3187.pdf), who report potential biases when using [ran3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16757154/1154578) from [Numerical Recipes](https://amzn.to/2SPrWWL) and the baseline Unix [drand48](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25276434/1154578). The paper is [discussed by Radford Neal](https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/non-random-mcmc/) in great details. See also this [discussion of PCG on X validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/337927/7224).

As a side note, I attended a session at MCM 2017 in Montréal, where one talk was pointing out at [discrepancies between GPU RNGs](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2017/07/07/mcm-2017-snapshots-2/), although a [toy experiment of mine](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2017/07/13/33889/) did not reveal any on the banana target of Haario et al. (1999):

$\qquad\qquad$ [image]